# Isolating Actual Resizing And Not Moving?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I can see that the ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd events are triggered also when a form is moved.

How can I trigger this code only on a resize and not on a move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SizeChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx)?